# How does tor network calculate relay status?

Tags: relays, directory

I have been working to get my relay marked as stable. I am aware that a relay needs to be running for 8 days to be listed as stable. I had it up to four solid days, but had to restart it tonight as my contact information was entered incorrectly. Despite only being off for one minute or so, torstatus.blutumage.de picked up that it restarted, and now reads “uptime: 0 days”. Does this mean I have to restart the 8 days over again from the start?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/dir-spec.txt#n2467) regarding the Stable flag:

> "Stable" -- A router is 'Stable' if it is active, and either its Weighted
>      MTBF is at least the median for known active routers or its Weighted MTBF
>      corresponds to at least 7 days. Routers are never called Stable if they are
>      running a version of Tor known to drop circuits stupidly.  (0.1.1.10-alpha
>      through 0.1.1.16-rc are stupid this way.)

(That's a direct link as of the time of writing. Look for Stable `3.4.2. Assigning flags in a vote`)

---

FYI for in the future: many (but not all) torrc changes only require a reload as opposed to a restart. Changing your ContactInfo is one of those things. That would have prevented the downtime.

Yes, to get the Stable flag you'll need to wait until your Mean Time Between Failures is above the network average or at least 7 days.

Don't worry too much about needing to restart your relay. Keeping your OS and Tor up to date is more important than shooting for as large of an uptime number as possible.

Just sit back, relax, and feel good about yourself because you contribute to the Tor network. Thank you for running a relay!

Comment: What does tor do with relays that are marked “stable”? It seems they use them for bigger connections, but my relay seems to receive loads of traffic anyway. Thank you.